# How to check if a number contains more than 1 of the same digit? (Java)

Tags: java, string, numbers

I'm trying to do this:

User inputs a number for example 2013 or 2012 and it checks if the number has any reoccurring digits like in 2012 there is 2 but I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   public static boolean hasDuplicates(String text){
        for(int i = 0; i < text.length() - 1; i++){
            for(int j = i + 1; j < text.length(); j ++){
                if(text.charAt(i) == text.charAt(j)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I'm going to give best answer to Helios Santos because one his code is understandable and because your explanations are mediocre.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it this way:

```
public static boolean containsDuplicate(int number) {
    String strNum = number.toString();
    for(int i=0; i < strNum.length() -1 ; i++){
          if( containsDuplicatedValue(strNum, strNum.charAt(i) )
              return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean containsDuplicatedValue(String str, char searchFor) {
    return str.indexOf(searchFor) != str.lastIndexOf(searchFor);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a -1 in the for loop?

Comment: And could you please explain what containsDuplicatedValue method does I don't seem to understand.

Comment: You don't need to check the last value with itself. That's why i used the -1

Comment: Yes, it  is just a tiny optimization.

Comment: str.indexOf(searchFor) // This method returns the first occurrence of the character.  str.lastIndexOf // This return the last one. So if the  returned position is the same it means we have found the same number.

Comment: Though why do we use != wouldn't we use ==? Lol kind of confusing to me sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to check for duplicates. If the first occurrence of `number` has a different index than the last occurrence, then `number` must occur more than once.

```
public static boolean containsDuplicate(String str, int number) {
    return str.indexOf(number) != str.lastIndexOf(number);
}
```

Comment: Err, its not only the last digit and the beginning it could be any digits, like 2021

Comment: @Ethylene, if the index of the first occurrence of the char is different than the index of the last occurrence of the char that means there are at least 2 chars with that value.
If the value is the same is guaranteed that the char has no duplicates. The method works if you run it 10 times. one for each number.

Comment: I honestly don't understand what is in the containsDuplicate method since I never used indexOf,

Comment: @Ethylene Did you bother to look at the Java documentation for `indexOf()`? Did you even try copying and pasting the code into an IDE and testing to see if it worked? Have you put any effort into this at all?